# IJavascriptCallback hangs application. CefSharp

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

When I execute a callback in the following way, the program completely freezes:

```
[JavascriptIgnore]
private async Task<bool> ExecuteCallback(IJavascriptCallback callback, params object[] parms)
        {
            if (callback != null && callback.CanExecute && !callback.IsDisposed)
            {
                JavascriptResponse response = await callback.ExecuteAsync(parms);
                return response.Success && bool.TryParse(response.Result?.ToString(), out bool result) && result;
            }
                return false;
        }
```

How do i create a browser:

```
        CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings()
        {
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
        };
        cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream");
        cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
        cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-usermedia-screen-capturing");
        if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
        {
           Cef.Initialize(cefSettings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
        }

        Browser = new HandBrowser("dummy:")
        {
            JsWorker = new JsWorker(),
        };
        Browser.Address = "www.google.ru";
        Browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true;
        Browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.NameConverter = null;
        Browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("worker", Browser.JsWorker, isAsync: false);
```

please tell me why it might be, I've already spent a lot of time looking for a problem.

Comment: You need to set http://cefsharp.github.io/api/90.6.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_ConcurrentTaskExecution.htm to true before you create your first ChromiumWebBrowser instance.  The default behaviour doesn't allow for methods that return a Task.

Comment: It did not help

Comment: You'll need to provide a complete example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I created a minimal project to reproduce the problem, please look at this. To reproduce it is enough to run the program. The problem is in the JsWorker.ExecuteCallback method
https://github.com/Muradin-Botashev/CefSharpExample

Comment: You are blocking in FrameLoadEnd creating a deadlock, use await or ContinueWith instead. Avoid blocking operations in the CefSharp events.

Comment: even if I wait for the page to load and call the execution of the callback by pressing the button, the program still hangs. Please help me figure it out

Comment: Switching Frameloadend to an async event and awaiting the call worked as expected when I tried.

Comment: In a real project, I do not need to call callbacks through browser events, I will do this through calls using buttons. I redid my example for this case, please see

Comment: Use async events and await all the calls.